# Avoid login form when is successful - Spring Security

Tags: spring, gwt, spring-security

I've done a custom login page for my Spring+GWT project, the login is successful and logout also, now I want that validate session when user go back in the browser and avoid the login form again, so if the user is logged the application should redirect to app instead of login form.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without details of your application, I cannot provide a very precise answer. However, generally speaking when you load your login page you can check to see if a user is authenticated and perform a redirect if the user is authenticated, else continue as normal. For example:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ...;
HttpServletResponse response = ...;

if(request.getRemoteUser() != null) {
    // perform redirect
} else {
    // render login page like normal
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm not using Spring Controllers but GWT for Front-End.

I'm loading the login.html form configuring URL patterns from spring-security.xml

¿There are some way to validate from URL pattern?